# Querying using custom key identifier(Name/ID) in firestore(datastore mode)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, gql, gqlquery

I have a datastore entity like this below

```
     Name/ID              Parent                       Rollen             email          first_name      last_name
name=CidassUID  Key(Tenant, 'CidassGroupID')    ["user","admin"]    user@email.com  user first name user last name
```

I would like to make a query w.r.t Name/ID

In GQL I am trying like this

```
 select * from User where Name/ID='CidassUID'
```

and in python like this..

```
    query = client.query(kind='User')
    query.add_filter('Name/ID', '=', 'name=CidassUID')
    return list(query.fetch())
```

Can somebody help how can I get the result via Name/ID?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thats how i solve it in GQL..

```
select * from User where __key__= Key(Tenant, 'CidassGroupID', User, 'CidassUID')
```

and for python..

```
query_key=client.key('Tenant', 'CidassGroupID','User', 'CidassUID')
query.key_filter(query_key,'=')
```

Comment: is therr any better way of doing it too?